# Xcode 5-DP5 Crashing when distributing

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, xcode5, osx-mavericks

I have been struggling past 4 days trying to Publish an app to App Store. But every single time I go on Xcode

`Project->Archive-> Distribute/Validate`

Have downloaded the right profile from iTunes Developer Center.

It crashes every time.

I have tried removing the itunnesconnect DB file that I read from previous posts but I couldnt find it

`$ rm ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/connect1.apple.com 4.6.1.db`

Got

`$ rm: /Users/{_USER_}/Library/Developer/Xcode/connect1.apple.com: No such file or directory`

`$ rm: 4.6.1.db: No such file or directory`

Also tried running:

`mkdir ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/OldPortalDBs; mv ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/connect1.apple.com* ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/OldPortalDB`

Getting similar error (As the file is indeed nonexistent. However this options were for Xcode 4

Here is the Details to the Crash: http://www.ipaste.org/NCj

I am running the following:

- Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks
- XCode 5-DP5
- MacBook Air Mid 2013
- PhoneGap/Cordova 3.0

Any help would be mostly appreciated, thank you

Comment: You're lucky, Xcode 5 has crashed upon launching on my machine since the 2nd beta :( Good luck getting this issue solved

Comment: xcode 5 is a preview version. you can not publish to app store with a beta version of Xcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Developer center clearly states that you cannot use any Developer Preview version to submit app to the App Store:

```
Xcode 5 Developer Preview cannot be used to submit apps to the iOS or Mac App Store. 
Continue to use the publicly released version of Xcode to compile and submit apps to the App Stores.
```

Source: Login to [iOS dev center](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/), choose iOS SDK Beta tab, see the "Read Me Before Downloading" section.

Comment: So we can't publish ios7 compatible app yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can't publish to the App Store using Xcode 5 (as per the release notes). Use Xcode 4.6.